# is binding simple a shortcut for addeventlistener

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, bindable, metatag

I never really understood the point of binding, beyond it being effectively shorthand for addeventlistener.

is there more to it? am I missing something?

thanks,
dsdsdsdsd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data binding is all about declaratively defining how data is displayed in the UI.  Under the hood, it is a bit more complicated, because there are more needs than just hooking `addEventListener` to support the features of data binding.

It is a very powerful feature, actually, and to understand it more, we can look at a simple "Hello World" application:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <s:HGroup>
        <s:TextInput id="input" />
        <s:Label text="Hello {input.text}" />
    </s:HGroup>

</s:Application>
```

Now, compile this app with the `--keep` compiler flag and look at the new folder "bin-debug/generated".  We are interested in HelloWorld-generated.as

Here is where that binding gets defined and called from the constructor:

```
private function _HelloWorld_bindingsSetup():Array
{
    var result:Array = [];

    result[0] = new mx.binding.Binding(this,
        function():String
        {
            var result:* = "Hello " + (input.text);
            return (result == undefined ? null : String(result));
        },
        null,
        "_HelloWorld_Label1.text"
        );


    return result;
}
```

A little later, in the HelloWorld constructor, you get a call to set up the watchers:

```
        _watcherSetupUtil.setup(this,
                function(propertyName:String):* { return target[propertyName]; },
                function(propertyName:String):* { return HelloWorld[propertyName]; },
                bindings,
                watchers);
```

Which really just does this:

```
watchers[0] = new mx.binding.PropertyWatcher("input", 
                                            { propertyChange: true }, 
                                            [ bindings[0] ] , 
                                            propertyGetter );
watchers[1] = new mx.binding.PropertyWatcher("text",
                                             { change: true,
                                               textChanged: true },
                                             [ bindings[0] ],
                                             null);
```

Things get more complicated with two-way bindings.

Answer (score 4):

Data Binding in Flex 4 COULD I guess be described as a shortcut for addEventListener() - but that's a bit like saying that cars are just a shortcut for walking. If you're only going around the block, no big deal - but if you're building a complex application with lots of item renderers and lots of data points that can vary at a moment's notice, data binding lets you avoid writing hundreds of addEventListener() and removeEventListener() calls, as well as their associated handlers. It's kind of a really big deal, in that context.

Comment: Agreed.  Data binding, when used properly, is extremely powerful and expressive.  It keeps the display of the data right where you expect it to be: where the UI element that displays it is.  It significantly reduces your code and allows you to decouple your data from your UI.  I make heavy use of this feature, as it is one of the best parts of the framework, IMO.

Comment: +1 from me too.  Binding can be very powerful.  My one caution is to avoid an overuse of binding.  Binding is often overused and can cause performance issues, especially in itemRenderers.  I solve a lot of memory issues for Flextras clients by rewriting their renderers to not use binding.  None of the Flex Framework components, for example, use Binding.  There is a reason for that.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com Even then, I would never say that one should avoid data binding in item renderers (you are not suggesting that either).  I use data binding in item renderers all the time and have never had perf problems. That being said, I believe they can exist.  Especially when going to mobile. This is a case of "understand your tool and make an educated decision". In the case of a component that will be used by everyone (like yours), it makes a ton of sense to avoid data binding.  You don't know how your component will be used. But in a list of 50 things and one binding, it is often fine.

Comment: Hmm, really? ItemRenderers get that super-handy bindable "data" property. You advise against binding against that? That was how I was taught to do it, but I'm the first to admit that I'm more of a Flash guy than a Flex guy so I could be wrong!

Comment: I think he is saying "be careful".  Perf can get bad with item renderers.  That doesn't mean it will.  Jeff (Flextras) develops components for everyone to use, so he needs to optimize for the worst case.  If you don't notice a problem, I wouldn't avoid binding in item renderers (I do it all the time too).  Just know that it is a likely place where you can experience perf problems.  I am a big fan of avoiding pre-optimization and this is a prime case for it :)  Fix it if it becomes a problem is my motto.